# Code first detect changes in database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm wondering whats the best way to go about if I want an event that will listen to changes made in the database when using EF Code First?

Like if I have a method `Update()` that will be raised if a change to the database is made like adding a user to it.

Comment: Is this what you want ??

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813933/can-i-call-a-c-sharp-function-by-a-sql-server-trigger

Comment: I' thinking more like something similiar to the ObservableCollection that has an event that get fired when it detect changes to the list(add, remove etc) but I want to be able to use it in code first so it will fire a event when it detect changes(add, remove) in the database.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do. My first impression is that you are trying to use EF for something that it is not supposed to solve. EF context should not be long living so what you are trying to do goes exactly against that best practice.

Answer (score 0):

What You think about this 
http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/c-sqldependency-monitoring

Comment: Please never just drop a link. Always give a brief summary and tell why you think it applies. Link rot is a serious disease.

Answer (score 0):

```
public MyContext() {
((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.SavingChanges += SavingChangesHandler;
}

private void SavingChangesHandler(object sender, EventArgs e) {

foreach (DbEntityEntry entry in ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(entry => entry.State == EntityState.Added || entry.State == EntityState.Modified || entry.State == EntityState.Deleted)) {
_log.DebugFormat("{0} Entity: {1}", entry.State.ToString(), entry.Entity.ToString().Contains("DynamicProxies") ? entry.Entity.GetType().BaseType.Name : entry.Entity.ToString());
if (entry.State != EntityState.Deleted) {
        var changedProperties = entry.CurrentValues.PropertyNames.Where(p => entry.Property(p).IsModified);
    changedProperties.ToList().ForEach(p => _log.DebugFormat("{0} changed from {1} to {2}", p, entry.Property(p).OriginalValue, entry.Property(p).CurrentValue));
    //TODO: handle complex properties
                }
            }
    }
```