# C# Scheduler for Project

Tags: c#, database, web-services, scheduler

I'm in the process of building a Scheduler in C sharp. The scheduler should ping the DataBase Queue and if anything new is written in the Database it should pick that up and send it to the remote server for processing. (The files will be uploaded to the database by the client using a WCF webservice) how do you guys think i should handle this situation? any type of help would be highly appreciated. I'm still in the design phase.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: I am literally coding out that exact same process.  That's weird.

Answer (score 1):

As this is a periodic task, I'd consider writing an app that does the job when run (with no scheduling). Then add it to the Windows Task Scheduler.

Comment: the scheduler will continuously run so that it can pick up stuff whenever it is written in the job queue. how should i approach it?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/). It easily lets you set up a scheduler and plug in Jobs (i.e. Send the files to the remote server) and Triggers (How often do you want it to run..) It has an excellent Fluent API as well as support for CRON style expressions.

There are also tutorials on the site, and google will find you a bunch more.

Answer (score 0):

@spender's idea is easy to implement. Another option is using a database trigger to call CLR proc

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx

[Can I call a C# function by a SQL Server trigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813933/can-i-call-a-c-sharp-function-by-a-sql-server-trigger)